# "Le voir faire à"

Tags: grammaire

Dans une traduction du Sophiste de Platon (Léon Robin, La Pléiade), on lit:

> D'un autre côté, il y a un petit point sur lequel tu as à t'expliquer : qu'est-ce qui est pour toi d'habitude le plus agréable? est-ce, dans l'exposition de ce que tu te proposes de mettre sous les yeux d'autrui, de prononcer en ton propre nom un long discours? ou bien de procéder par interrogations, ainsi que jadis je l'ai vu faire à Parménide, dont les propos étaient au surplus admirables, ce jour où je fus mis en sa présence, alors que j'étais, moi, tout jeune, et lui déjà tout à fait vieux?

Je ne comprends pas la construction "je l'ai vu faire à Parménide"; j'aurais écrit: "j'ai vu Parménide le faire". Dans l'expression "je l'ai vu faire à Parménide", à quoi renvoie le pronom "l'"?

edit: Comme demandé par @xhienne, j'apporte les précisions suivantes. Je n'avais pas imaginé la possible interprétation selon laquelle c'est à Parménide qu'on posait des questions et j'avais cru comprendre que c'était Parménide qui posait des questions. Une autre traduction donne: "à quelle méthode, pour mener à
bien ta démonstration, va ta préférence, un discours long, ou bien des interrogations, comme celles utilisées jadis par Parménide, qui développa des
arguments merveilleux en ma présence, lorsque j’étais jeune et qu’il était déjà très vieux ?" (Flammarion) Par ailleurs, le contexte est le suivant: Socrate s'adresse ici à l'Etranger qui va dire préférer la seconde méthode et c'est lui qui va poser des questions alors qu'il est supposé procéder comme Parménide. Enfin, dans le texte grec, Parménide est à l'accusatif et non au datif, mais je ne suis pas assez compétent pour être sûr que ce soit un élément probant.

Cette interprétation alternative est celle de @Rhubarb et était celle de @xhienne avant qu'il ne donne une nouvelle réponse en pointant une construction que je ne connaissais pas.

Comment: Deux commentaires extraits de https://fr.wikibooks.org/wiki/Pour_lire_Platon/Conseils_pour_la_lecture : *Par exemple, il serait peu judicieux de commencer à lire Platon par le Parménide, dialogue très abstrait dont la compréhension pose de gros problèmes à tous les commentateurs.* et *Les traductions de Robin et Diès ont une réputation excellente, mais elles peuvent être parfois difficiles à lire, du fait de leur fidélité au texte grec.*

Comment: Il ne s'agit pas du Parménide ici mais du Sophiste. Je suis rassuré de lire que la traduction de Robin est supposée être difficile à lire. Sa renommée me faisait justement penser qu'il ne pouvait pas s'agir d'une erreur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il est vrai que la tournure surprend. D'après le [TLFi](https://cnrtl.fr/definition/voir), la construction 
« Avoir vu faire quelque chose à quelqu'un » (aujourd'hui désuète) signifie « Avoir vu quelqu'un faire quelque chose ».

Ceci explique aussi des constructions comme « Lui avoir vu faire qqc » (plutôt que « L'avoir vu faire qqc ») ou « Leur avoir vu faire qqc » (plutôt que « Les avoir vu faire qqc »). Exemple tiré de la [4ème édition du dictionnaire de l'Académie Française](https://cnrtl.fr/definition/academie4/t%C3%A9moigner) : « Je témoignerai par tout ce que je lui ai vu faire. ».

Votre phrase indique que Socrate a assisté à une séance de questions posées par Parménide. Le pronom « l » correspond donc à « procéder par interrogations ».

Comment: Ce ne serait donc pas Parménide qui posait des questions, comme j'avais cru le comprendre. Pourtant, dans le reste du dialogue, c'est l'Etranger, à qui s'adresse ici Socrate, qui pose des questions. La traduction chez Flammarion: "à quelle méthode, pour mener à bien ta démonstration, va ta préférence, un discours long, ou bien des interrogations, comme celles utilisées jadis par Parménide, qui développa des arguments merveilleux en ma présence, lorsque j’étais jeune et qu’il était déjà très vieux ?"

Comment: @Daniel, mes connaissances philosophiques sont proches du zéro absolu et peuvent donc me conduire à des contre-sens comme vous le soulignez à juste titre. Je pense que vos précisions auraient leur place dans votre question. La lecture de votre traduction alternative m'a fait revoir complètement ma réponse, même si la conclusion reste la même.

Answer (score 0):

C'est dommage que la réponse precédente ait été retirée. Je crois bien que cette tournure indique que le rôle de Parménide n'était pas de poser ces questions, mais d'y répondre. Il n'en demeure pas moins que c'est lui qui a fait le choix de procéder par cette méthode, ce que pourrait justifier la traduction de Flammarion, citée dans un commentaire désormais supprimé : « à quelle méthode, pour mener à bien ta démonstration, va ta préférence, un discours long, ou bien des interrogations, comme celles utilisées jadis par Parménide ».

Comment: Vous avez raison mais ma réponse comportait un contre-sens du fait de la présence inattendue de cette préposition "à", qui est aussi la source de l'étonnement de Daniel. Je vais rétablir ma réponse et apporter les explications nécessaires.